# VS Code Replace Rules Extension - how to replace with uppercase

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

In VS Code I'm using the extension Replace Rules.

In settings I'm hoping to use this regex to replace any finds with their uppercase versions:

```
"replacerules.rules": {
    "uppcase all keywords": {
      "flags": "i",
      "find": "(?<!\\w)(create|select|sum||drop|table|if|exists|day|group|by|order|min|max|and|else|iif|end|over|partition|distinct|desc)(?!\\w)",
      "replace": "\\U$1"
    }
```

The flag is working ok as is the Find but the replace is not changing the first captured group to Uppercase - why?

---

Edit

Wiktor has given the reason - that Javascript does not support this functionality in the replace clause.

If this extension will not do what I require is there a way I can save this regex for use through the command palate in VS Code?

Comment: [*Replace Rules uses JavaScript regular expressions for searching and replacing.*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules) - JavaScript regex does not support case changing operator in the replacement.

Comment: It would be easy to write a one-off extension that did this or another option is to set up a snippet.  Do you want to see either of these.

Comment: @Mark I imagined "writing a one-off extension" would be pretty involved? I guess info on that option would interest me the most as an answer as it would be very flexible. 
Not sure how the snippet option would be used - I'd have to still transfer the snippets to the find/replace boxes whenever I want to apply it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a snippet approach:

```
{
  "key": "alt+u",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
      "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(?<!\\w)(create|select|sum|drop|table|if|exists|day|group|by|order|min|max|and|else|iif|end|over|partition|distinct|desc)(?!\\w)/${1:/upcase}/g}",
  }
}
```

Snippets can transform to upper case: `${1:/upcase}` means upcase the 1st capture group.

But for this to work the text you want to transform must be selected.  You can simply select the entire document <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then trigger the snippet.  You could combine those operations into a macro if you wish.

You could also make that into a snippet in a snippet file and then insert it through the Command Palette command `Insert Snippet` (which unfortunately seems to only filter by prefix not description - although it does show the description).

[image: snippet transform demo]

---

Extension demo:

[image: extension find and transform]

This extension version uses your Search (across files) functionality, but you can limit it to the current file.  Using this Search route you must accept the replacement dialog, there is no way to avoid that.  But it gives you a nice command in the Command Palette `Find-Transform:<your command title here>` that could also be bound to a keybinding.

Or you can use its find in the current file and replace functionality - which will just perform the changes immediately.

Either way you can save these commands with search/replace regex's that **support** the case modifiers `\\U`, `\\u`, `\\L` and `\\l` in conjunction with capture groups of course in the replace value.

[Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform) is the extension.

Comment: this is very kind of you Mark - appreciate the time writing these answers [I'd guess you are connected professionally to this product?]

Comment: I set up the snippet you detailed in my key binding json file - works great.
Do you have any references that I can go to to understand how to put together the extension? It looks really cool